# High Performance WPF Datagrid

Tags: wpf, performance, datagrid, scroll

My issue in a nutshell : we are currently using in our project the standard WPF dataGrid, which comes with WPF .NET4 and above. Unfortunately for us, the performances are horrible for the scale of data we're using (not that much actually, let's say up to 200 columns * 50~100 rows) : either the loading time is to high (more than 10 sec with our customisation) when virtualization is disabled, either the horizontal scrolling is too sluggish to be acceptable. Deffered scrolling is currently used, but this is rather a workaround than a real fix (and its use is counter intuitive for columns IMO)

The requirements are not that high when you think of it: basically, an editable grid, with support for cell template and cell selection (there is no sorting, grouping, filtering for now).

We've spent much time doing "micro-optimization" (among those all kinds of virtualization...) to get better results, but, in a way or another the conclusion is that the WPF datagrid is a very low performance grid. It's all the more evident when building a sample project, with just a WPF datagrid of the required size: even without any customization, the performance issues are obvious.

So, I'm currently looking for a "high performance" datagrid or solution which fullfill the above requirements. I've had a look at the WPF extended toolkit grid, but I've have not been convinced... A listview + gridview gave good performance, but there is no support for any cell-level operation (selection...). Actually it seems most of the datagrid on the market scales well with a lot of rows, but very poorly when the column numbers exceed 10-20.

Comment: What are you binding it to?  A DataTable is also slow.  What I did was a ListView Gridview.  For edit there is a detail of the current selected row.  200 columns by 100 rows is still about 1-2 seconds to load.  If you think the requirements are not all that high then write your own editable grid.

Comment: Datatable is bound to an object model (MVVM pattern) and showing a combination of text and figures (no images, but some styling). By "not that high", I meant functionality speaking : we all know achieving good performance is not that easy, that why I'm asking for help. Sure writing a custom grid is an option, but as I said, I'm perfecty know that it's far more difficult that one's might think. So, if there is another option/component to consider, I welcome it.

Comment: @Jallal From the point of user experience and usability a table with 200 columns and 100 rows is difficuilt to handle. So if I would be the user I won't use it. Sure that you don't have another possibility to visualize your data?

Comment: @DHN I agree with you regarding the usability POV. Most of our screens shows a datagrid of 10 columns*25 rows, where no performance issues occur. But there are two cases were the users may choose to display a significant number of columns and, for those (who are likely to occurs regularly BTW, as it has been a request from the users to have those kinds of screens) WPF standard datagrid performance is sub-par (especially regarding the column scaling, WPF datagrid seems to scale well with big numbers of rows). FI, it is rather 200 col*25 rows for the 1st case and 50 col*100 rows for the 2nd.

Comment: @Jallal Post the relevant code and XAML.

Comment: Correct DataGrid does lots or rows better than it does lots of columns.  I disagree with the assertion you are locking into 200 columns because the user asked for it.  That is UI design and the job of the developer.  Respond that a large number of columns is slow.  Show them a fast master detail.